# Is it possible that phone camera shoots video with irregular fps?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, camera, frame-rate

My goal is to synchronize movie’s frames with device orientation data from phone’s gyroscope/accelerometer. Android provides orientation data with proper timestamps. As for a video its frame rate known only in general. Experiments show that changes in orientation measured by accelerometer don’t match changes in the scene. Sometimes it goes faster, sometimes it goes slower during the same video.

Is there any way to find out how much time passed between two consequent frames?

Comment: system clock maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to answer this question myself.

First, yes, it is possible that fps or frame rate is not constant. Here is the quote from Android Developers Guide: *“NOTE: On some devices that have auto-frame rate, this sets the maximum frame rate, not a constant frame rate.”*

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoFrameRate%28int%29

Second, there is a function get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) in OpenCV VideoCapture class that allows reading current frame time position:

```
VideoCapture capture("test.mp4");
double curFrameTime;
double prevFrameTime = 0;
double dt;
while (capture.grab())
{
  curFrameTime = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC); //Current frame position
  dt = curFrameTime - prevFrameTime;  //Time difference
  prevFrameTime = curFrameTime;  //Previous frame position
} 
capture.release();
```

If there is a better suggestion I’ll be glad to see it.